# The subtle difference between #ifdef and #if for a macro defined as 0

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Given the C file below:

```
$ cat macros.c
#ifdef MACRO
#  error MACRO is defined
#else
#  error MACRO is undefined
#endif
#if MACRO
#  error MACRO is non-zero
#else
#  error MACRO is zero
#endif
```

What is the expected output of the following?

```
$ gcc           -c macros.c
$ gcc -DMACRO   -c macros.c
$ gcc -DMACRO=0 -c macros.c
```

**Answer**: Here's what the gcc's preprocessor on my machine does.

```
$ gcc           -c macros.c
macros.c:4:4: error: #error MACRO is undefined
macros.c:9:4: error: #error MACRO is zero
$ gcc -DMACRO   -c macros.c
macros.c:2:4: error: #error MACRO is defined
macros.c:7:4: error: #error MACRO is non-zero
$ gcc -DMACRO=0 -c macros.c
macros.c:2:4: error: #error MACRO is defined
macros.c:9:4: error: #error MACRO is zero
$
```

**Lesson**: `#ifdef MACRO` evaluates to true for defined-ness *even if the defined value is 0 (zero)*.

Another C preprocessor gotcha! Is this how it should be as per the C standard?

Comment: I dispute that the difference is particularly "subtle", nor any sort of "gotcha". It seems fairly clear and intuitive to me. `#ifdef` stands for "if defined". Why do you think the value would have anything to do with it there? Perhaps coming from PHP/Javascript lazy comparisons?

Comment: Defining a macro to have the value `0`, or `fred` or `""` or anything else, is still in fact defining that macro, so it would seem to me that `#ifdef` should report that the macro is defined if it has been defined - it doesn't care what it's defined value is, just that it has been defined...

Comment: Your question could be answered by you reading the standard; why are you asking other people to read it for you?

Answer (score 9):

Any undefined macro is treated as it were defined as 0 for the purposes of evaluating the controlling expressions of `#if` statements.  From C99 §6.10.1/3-4 (emphasis added):

> 3) Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> `# if constant-expression new-line group`<sub>`opt`</sub>
>   `# elif constant-expression new-line group`<sub>`opt`</sub>
>
> check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.
>
> 4) Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become
>   the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified
>   by the `defined` unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token `defined` is
>   generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the `defined` unary operator
>   does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is
>   undefined. **After all replacements due to macro expansion and the `defined` unary
>   operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
>   identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each preprocessing
>   token is converted into a token. [...]

So, for example, expressions like this:

```
#if !FOO
```

Will evaluate to `1` if `FOO` is undefined, since it will be treated as a 0, and then `!FOO` would be evaluated as `!0`, which is `1`.

Answer (score 7):

`#ifdef`  only cares if MACRO has been defined or not. Value doesn't matter.

`#if`  checks for the value of MACRO and evaluates MACRO accordingly.

That is correct behaviour

Comment: This does not answer the question of how undefined identifiers are evaluated in the expressions in `#if` statements.

Comment: That's clearly defined in the C and C++ standard - identifiers that are not #define'd as macros are replaced with 0 in a #if or #elif statement. That should be common knowledge.

Comment: I can confirm that the behaviour of `#if` when the symbol is not defined is the same as if it is defined with a `0` value.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is as per the standard.

**C99 Standard: 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion:**

Para 2: Preprocessing directives of the forms

```
# if constant-expression new-line groupopt
# elif constant-expression new-line groupopt
```

check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.

Para 4: Preprocessing directives of the forms

```
# ifdef identifier new-line groupopt
# ifndef identifier new-line groupopt
```

check whether the identifier is or is not currently defined as a macro name. Their
conditions are equivalent to `#if defined` *identifier* and `#if !defined` *identifier*
respectively.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how undefined identifiers are evaluated in the expressions in `#if` statements.

Comment: Read the answer above, or the C standard. Google for N1570 to download the latest free draft of the standard.

Comment: But we can use `#ifdef` with `#elif`. If we `#define` macro with value `0` for `#ifdef` case, the `#ifdef` case tests it to true. Otherwise, if we `#define` macro with value `0` for `#elif` case, the `#elif` case test it to **false**.