# Undeclared Macros in C

Tags: c, macros

This piece of code works perfectly and gives output as 4.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#if X==5
#define Y 5
#else
#define Y 4
#endif
void main()
{
    printf("%d",Y);
}
```

While this piece of code returns an error saying "X undeclared".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#if X==5
#define Y 5
#else
#define Y 4
#endif
void main()
{
    printf("%d",X);
}
```

If a macro is not defined, the pre-processor should assign it to 0 by default.  Then why I'm not getting the output as '0' in the second piece of code?  If X is undeclared, as per the error, how was the undeclared macro be compiled successfully, without any error in the first piece of code?  Kindly explain in simple terms.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, the error message verbatim!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312617/the-subtle-difference-between-ifdef-and-if-for-a-macro-defined-as-0 - *Any undefined macro is treated as it were defined as 0 for the purposes of evaluating the controlling expressions of #if statements.* but not otherwise.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. Whoever or whatever told you to use `void main()` does not know C well enough to be teaching it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Hundreds of universities will have to closed around the world if we stopped incapable people from teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after the preprocessor text substitution the `X` isn't replaced because is not defined anywhere, and you get an undefined variable error.

An undefined macro symbol has value 0 for the preprocessor, but only in a preprocessor conditional expression (i.e. `#if`, `#elif`), not in a C statement.